# Is it safe to use ThreadStatic integer variable in ASP.NET MVC BeginRequest

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I am setting ThreadStatic integer variable `TenantId` in my ASP.NET MVC application.

I get `TenantId` in a request header and I read request headers in `Begin_Request` event of the ASP.NET MVC app and set it to this ThreadStatic `TenantId` variable.

I make use of this `TenantId` in the entire application, for example when registering `DbContext` and saving tenant specific info in redis cache.

Questions

1. Is there a possibility that this `TenantId` can be set as 0 or `null`?
2. For every user login, will I get unique `TenantId` of that user?
3. Is using a threadstatic `TenantId` a good approach?

I tried conditional debugging to check if `TenantId` is getting set to 0, and it does set it as 0 (I don't know how)

Comment: ...don't do this: `ThreadStatic` doesn't flow with `async` calls: ASP.NET-for-.NET Framework only _barely_ supports .NET 4.5 `Task`-based async methods and there's a lot of gotchas - rather than hacking around problems that don't need to exist, just store per-request values in your `HttpContext.Items`.

Comment: Why not use a simple `static` field?

Comment: Dai : I need to use this in services \ business logic layer , will be good to use HttpContext in service layer ?

Comment: @Sagar : _"I need to use this in services \ business logic layer"_ - if you're crossing layer boundaries then you **definitely** should not be using `static` fields to pass data around. The solution is to pass all data through method parameters.